# Why I am getting a null pointer at my getter

Tags: java, android

Please give me a clue why I am getting a null pointer where I am getting the value of getlatitude and how I can fix it??

Main Activity

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        p = new Proximity();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


        initLocationFetching(MainActivity.this); 
}

 @Override
    public void locationFetched(Location mLocal, Location oldLocation, String time, String locationProvider) {
        super.locationFetched(mLocal, oldLocation, time, locationProvider);
        p.setLatitude(mLocal.getLatitude());
        p.setLongitude(mLocal.getLongitude()); 
}
```

On My fragment where I am getting the value

```
  Proximity p = new Proximity();

    public MapFragment(Context c, Activity a) { context = c; activity = a;}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contact_us, container, false);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            checkLocationPermission();
        }
        // Initializing
        MarkerPoints = new ArrayList<>();

        Toast.makeText(context, "Asdasdasdasdas"+p.getLatitude().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Proximity

```
public class Proximity {
    Double latitude;

    public Double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(Double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public Double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(Double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    Double longitude;
}
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.mark/com.mark.activity.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
>                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                          at com.fragment.MapFragment.onCreateView(MapFragment.java:113)
>                                                          at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2239)
>                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1332)
>                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1574)
>                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1641)
>                                                          at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:794)
>                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2415)
>                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2200)
>                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2153)
>                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2063)
>                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388)
>                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:554)
>                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:177)
>                                                          at com.mark.BaseActivityLocation.onStart(BaseActivityLocation.java:135)
>                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1174)
>                                                          at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5437)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2168)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

Comment: Hi Ayush Khare, `  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                       at .fragment.MapFragment.onCreateView(MapFragment.java:113)
                                                  
                                                                               at .BaseActivityLocation.onStart(BaseActivityLocation.java:135)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1174)`

Comment: Could you show the code in the line 113 of the error: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.fragment.MapFragment.onCreateView(MapFragment.java:113)`

Comment: Hi Dat Nguyen, `   Toast.makeText(context, "Asdasdasdasdas"+p.getLatitude().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` I'm having a null pointer at p.getLatitude()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your fragment you have created an object p 
`Proximity p = new Proximity();`
But the member variable `latitude` (Assuming that it is an object) is not set. i.e. latitude is null.
As per the logs, in `MapFragment.java: line no. 113` you are trying to access it. I think it is the code to show `Toast` where `p.getLatitude().toString()` results in NullPointerException.

You may have to pass `Proximity` instance to fragment either using `Fragment.setArguments` while adding the fragment or create a method in your fragment and access it from activity.
As the code for `Proximity` is not a posted I assume that lat and long are Objects not primitive data types.

Comment: Hi VishnuSP, on my MainActivity I set the arguments of latitude and longitude and want to get the value of it on another class where Fragment is extended. Pls. check above updated post.

Comment: Also, will I be initialize it on locationFetched() like   `p = new Proximity();
        p.setLatitude(mLocal.getLatitude());
        p.setLongitude(mLocal.getLongitude());`

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, you need to use `Fragment.setArguments` while adding/replacing/creating the fragment instance to pass the data/objects. As you have a custom model object, you need to use Parcelable interface (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.)html